# Where did my Windows go?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. I was trying to dual boot my Windows 7 PC.
SO, I made a bootable USB and proceeded to install Ubuntu 12.04

I am aware that during installation there are three options:
1. Install alongside Windows 7
2. Get rid of Windows 7
3. Something else

Well, the `Something else` option gave me something else than what I thought.

Before I installed Ubuntu I had 4 partitions (including System Reserve), C D E.
C is where Windows 7 was 
D is where data was (and still is)
E is where I decided to install Ubuntu.

So, I went to the `Something Else` option, selected the `/sda4/` which was `E:/` drive and clicked on `Install Now`.
All went well. On restart, it started Ubuntu (**wasn't I supposed to get an option to boot either this or Windows 7?**)

Now, the data is there. However, I do not get the option to start Windows. How do I get that option back ?

**Update:**
Here is what I have tried so far:
1. Manually editing the GRUB entries
2. Try BoorRepair

By using boot repair I can boot to either Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
However, there is no option to choose from the two at start up.

Comment: Take a look at [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: @Mitch Looks like I might screw up again

Comment: Why, what happened?

Comment: @Mitch Given my level of competence (or incompetence) , I might screw up

Comment: Carefully follow the instructions in the link, and you should be OK.

Comment: Open a terminal (ctrl + Alt + T) and type `sudo fdisk -l`. Add this information to your question. This will help us understand what's on your hard disk.

Comment: @ToDo http://imgur.com/hpsFmYM

Comment: It seems your windows is on sda2 or sda3. When you installed Ubuntu, where did you install grub? You should have installed it in `/dev/sda`.

Comment: In Ubuntu try viewing what's in sda2 and sda3 and see where you find the /Windows directory. That's your Windows installation.

Comment: @ToDo `/dev/sda4` is where Ubuntu is.  Win7 is on `/sda2`

Answer (score 2):

Try repairing grup. Alongside you can add windows to the bootmenue if not already present after repairing and updating grup.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried this too. Se my update :)

Comment: @FaiyazGhole - after using boot-repair it gives you a paste URL - please add that to your question so that we can see what it tried to repair.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you chose 'Something else' instead of 'Install alongside Ubuntu', so it won't realize you have Windows installed and therefore GRUB won't let you choose. Make sure GRUB is installed (`sudo apt-get install grub` if it isn't) then run `update-grub` in the terminal and restart.

Comment: I tried the `alongside` option but every time I clicked it, my PC kept restarting.

Comment: Ok. Did you try updating GRUB?

Comment: Yes, sir, downloading in progress.

Comment: command not found for `grub-update`

Comment: Sorry it's update-grub not grub-update. Try that ;)

Comment: `Could not find /boot/grub/menu.lst file. Would you like /boot/grub/menu.lst generated for you? (y/N)`

Comment: Try choosing 'y'

Comment: `line 1099: /boot/grub/menu.lst: Permission denied` Guess it also needs a `sudo` ?

Comment: Ah, I forgot - you need to run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: `Found GRUB 2: /boot/grub/core.img Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done`

Comment: Try restarting now.

Comment: No, no luck. Still does not ask for option.

Comment: So it just boots straight to Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you checked the files still exist?

Comment: Yes, it goes straight to Ubuntu

Comment: Here are the files: http://imgur.com/9cc6wAn

Comment: Try reading this, maybe you can manually add it: http://ma65p.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/how-to-edit-grubs-boot-menu-adding-an-os/

Comment: Going according to your reference, this is where I have to add the data right ? http://imgur.com/mXX62vK See the bottom part of GEdit

Comment: Yes, you need to make an entry like this:

Comment: title  Windows 7
root  (hd0,3)
makeactive
chainloader +1

Comment: You said sda4 which is equivalent to (hd0,3) according to step 8

Comment: Are you sure that is the right section ? Or would you like a pastebin of the entire text ?

Comment: I said `/dev/sda4 is where Ubuntu is` :)

Comment: Try it, I think it should work... Just remember to add the [enters] back in (StackOverflow removed them)

Comment: You mean I should press enter after writing a command ? Here is the paste bin of the GEDit : http://pastebin.com/Bk9fqZCy

Comment: I tried what you said. Didnt work. Maybe I pasted it in the wrong place ?

Comment: Here is what it should look like: http://sta.sh/0xce3lawc0u (See the bottom bit)

Comment: Tried but didnt work. I put it in different sports and tried. No luck

Comment: I'm not sure what else you can do, sorry...

Comment: @DevilishDB - please dont have conversations in comments - its very difficult to understand what has/hasn't been tried.  Please summarise what you have answered to-date by editing your answer before deleting your existing comments.  Thanks.

Comment: @FaiyazGhole - similar comment - the way we respond to answers is by editing your question with more detail.  Please do so now, and delete your old comments.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom Please See the update